# TinyMCE in impresspages plugin trouble

Tags: plugins, impresspages

At first, it is need to know I get active the **FullTinyMCe** and **TinyMCEComplete** plugins in Impresspages. Well, I have a new plugin where I have a field like this:

```
$fields[] = array(
    'label' => 'Rich Text to Store',
    'field' => 'textToStore',
    'type' => 'RichText',
    'preview' => '\Plugin\MyPlugin\Helper::previewText'
);
```

How do I do to force the type *RichText* using the versatility of the **FullTinyMCE** instead of internal configuration? I need other skills in this field like html edit and save for instance.

Thanks for the aid!

Answer (score 0):

These plugins alter the config just for themselves. If you want to update TinyMCE globally, change the implementation of ipTinyMceConfig() function. This is the default function that provides the configuration of TinyMCE. Replace it with your own function (this is all about JavaScript) that returns your custom configuration. That will take affect everywhere on ImpressPages. More about that:

https://www.impresspages.org/docs/tinymce

Comment: I replaced ipTinyMceConfig()a already. It's OK. In the plugin field editor to the richedit is displaying the menus and so on. However when I click in source code menu the source code editor open but disabled for edition. No typing is possible, nothing... Any Idea? My code replace is like this: